# How to disable the automatic mute after booting in gnome?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, volume

Whenever I start up, gnome sets the volume to mute automatically. So how can I ask it to remember the volume last time I set before shutting down?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the package `alsa-utils`, it will persist the volume across reboots:

```
# pacman -S alsa-utils
```